# .htaccess remove duplicate part of a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

some bug in my online catalog SEF URL generation created a situation where some category slug is added to the URL twice. to fix this i would like to use .htaccess to remove the this part of the URL and have the whole URL shift up one level including URL's which also include a product under them.

the duplicate occurrence is of the sub-category `painting-tools` under the category `tools`

so the wrong URL looks like this:
    /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/painting-tools
or
    /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/painting-tools/{some product}

instead of being the correct URL like this:

```
 /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools
```

or
     /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/{some product}

and the URLs

```
  /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/
```

or
      /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/{some product}

should actually be like this

```
  /store/items/catalog/tools
```

or
      /store/items/catalog/tools/{some product}

tried using this rule, but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^/painting-tools/painting-tools/(.*) /painting-tools/$1 [QSA]
```

i think the ^ part is not correct since its not the beginning of the URL.
How can i fix it ?
thanks

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? in root or in subfolder?

Comment: @starkeen - in the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this back-reference based redirect rule as **very first rule** in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?/([^/]+))/\2(/.*)?$ $1/$3 [NE,L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.+?/tools)/painting-tools(?:/.*)?$ $1/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

It is capturing repeat value after initial part and grouping it in this sub-pattern `([^/]+)`. Later in the regex it is using back-reference `\2` to make sure same captured value is repeated.

**Make sure you have proper `RewriteBase` defined to either `/` or `/store/` wherever your htaccess is located.**

---

**Update:** As per discussion below:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?/tools)/painting-tools2(/.*)?$ $1$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

This will remove `/painting-tools2` from URLs.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, thanks this works, but partially. it doesn't make the directory:
/store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/painting-tools
into
/store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools

Comment: sorry @anubhanva, your solution works, but i added another requirement for /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools (and anything under it)
should go here
/store/items/catalog/tools/

Comment: problem is, /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/painting-tools
is now going here:
/store/items/catalog/tools/
i  want it to go here /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools

Comment: ok, i'll just explain, im sorry for not being clear. the main purpose of this is to go up one level when tools/painting-tools  or tools/painting-tools/painting-tools  (and anything under them) appears.
this includes tools/painting-tools/painting-tools/{product} and tools/painting-tools   tools/painting-tools/{product}

Comment: tools/painting-tools/painting-tools/{product} should go here tools/painting-tools/{product}   i don't have redirect examples, my understanding in this matter is limited

Comment: I meant examples of URLs before and after redirect

Comment: i see, i thought mod_rewrite only runs once each page load so there wouldn't be a problem. what if i change the category name "painting-tools" slug to something else like "painting-tools-2", so only old links would have to be redirected. would that help ?

Comment: ok, assuming i change to painting-tools-2, what rewrite rule should i then use ?

Comment: what i didn't think about is if i change to painting-tools-2, it might duplicate itself in the same way wont it ? like this:
/store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools-2/painting-tools-2
so we are back in square one.
what i meant was that i drop the URL's created by the bug , and then we redirect from /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools/painting-tools
to /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools-2
and from /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools to /store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools

Comment: No URL should be `/store/items/catalog/tools/painting-tools-2/painting-tools` i.e. change only first part to `/painting-tools-2` otherwise due to your 2nd requirement rules will fire again. Only way to stop it is by adding a new cookie or query parameter after first redirect.