# Eliminate duplicate directory name in url using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

For some reason, I'm getting duplicate directory names in some urls within a subfolder on our website.  This seems to affect only crawlers as the files within this directory work fine when navigated.

I'd like to simply remove the duplicate directory name and make mydomain.com/sub/sub redirect to mydomain.com/sub.

I've tried many versions but my .htaccess skills are lacking apparently.  I currently have (not working of course):

```
RewriteRule ^mydomain.com/sub/sub/(.*) mydomain.com/sub/$1  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You must not put mydomain.com. Also there are lots of variables in play here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456587/htaccess-remove-duplicate-part-of-a-url

Comment: Yeah, I've tried without the domain.  Thanks for the link.  I see how the url is split and reassembled in that example but if I do something similar it won't work: RewriteRule ^(.+?/sub)/sub(/.*)?$ $1$2 [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: You are trying to cure the symptom instead of solving the actual issue. That rarely is a good idea. Why don't you find out instead what the actual issue is, so where those faulty URLs come from?

Comment: The short answer is expediency and the framework in that sub directory is not mine and is poorly documented in my opinion.  I have invested time examining the root cause already and have come up short.  Was hoping for a little help with the syntax as I rarely get into any real htaccess work other than simple redirects...

Comment: For syntax help I would actually point to the documentation of the rewriting module. As typical for OpenSource solutions it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^mydomain.com/sub/sub/(.*) mydomain.com/sub/$1  [L,R=301]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only - you appear to have included (part of) the domain name. Also, `mydomain.com` in the *substitution string* is going to be seen as a relative *subdirectory*.

Assuming you have a limited number of subdirectories where this occurs then to reduce `/sub/sub/<something>` to just `/sub/<something>` you would do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub/sub/(.*) /sub/$1  [R=301,L]
```

If you have other directives in you `.htaccess` file, then this needs to go near the top.

First test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. Clear your browser cache before testing.

But to echo @arkascha's comment... the reason why crawlers are finding these URLs in the first place would seem to be a fault in your URL structure/internal links - so this is what ultimately needs to be fixed.